# Is MapsInitializer.initialize() thread-safe?

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using [MapsInitializer.initialize(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapsInitializer.html#initialize%28android.content.Context%29) method to prepare Google Maps Android API v2 internals for my MapView. Currently it gets called during hosting Fragment's *onCreateView()* on an UI-thread, and this causes some noticable hickup before this fragment gets shown.

Therefore I'm thinking about putting this call in some thread/AsyncTask to perform init in the background.

Documentation doesn't mention if it is safe to do so, maybe fellow developers here know the answer? :)

Answer (score 5):

The best thing about `MapsInitializer` is that you can forget about it completly.

From the documentation you linked to:

> If you are using MapFragment or MapView and have already obtained a (non-null) GoogleMap by calling getMap() on either of these classes, then it is not necessary to call this.

If you have problems obtaining non-null `GoogleMap` this is not to be resolved by `MapsInitializer`, but rather updating Google Play Services on the device.

Comment: Looks like the docs are wrong. I tried calling getMap() in onCreateView(), it returns non-null object, but then when I try to call *CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(...)* it throws an NPE "*CameraUpdateFactory not initialized*". This was why I explicitly put that method, it fixes this crash.